# Issue in comparing 2 csv files data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, file-handling

I have 2 csv files that I want to compare and print row which is different or not present in fil2.csv.

```
value data
a      67
b      654
c      87
d      789
e      23
```

file2.csv

```
value data
a      67
b      654
c      87
d      7
```

desired output

```
d      789
e      23
```

I tried this code but it doesn't able to print differences.

```
reader1 = csv.reader(open(file1.csv, 'r'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
data = next(reader1)
reader2 = csv.reader(open(file2.csv, 'r'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
data2 = next(reader2)
if (data[0] != data2[0]) and (data[1] != data2[1]):
    print(data[0] , data[1])
```

Comment: Your column 0 values in your example match, so your if statement will always be false, so nothing will be printed.

Comment: It will ignore the missing values also? @RufusVS

Comment: To decide the best way to process your data, you need to know the data set.  Are the numbers in the first column all unique and ascending?  Or can there be duplicates or random order in the file?

Comment: They are not duplicates and will be in order @RufusVS

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a couple of boolean masks:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = [{'value': 'a', 'data': 67},
 {'value': 'b', 'data': 654},
 {'value': 'c', 'data': 87},
 {'value': 'd', 'data': 789},
 {'value': 'e', 'data': 23}]

d2 = [{'value': 'a', 'data': 67},
 {'value': 'b', 'data': 654},
 {'value': 'c', 'data': 87},
 {'value': 'd', 'data': 7}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

print(df1)

  value  data
0     a    67
1     b   654
2     c    87
3     d   789
4     e    23

print(df2)

value  data
0     a    67
1     b   654
2     c    87
3     d     7

not_in = ~df1['value'].isin(df2['value'])

data_diff = df1[~not_in]['data'] != df2['data']

print(df1[not_in | data_diff])

  value  data
3     d   789
4     e    23
```

For this answer `df1` and `df2` are use in place of `reader1` and `reader2` via `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: With this code, I am getting - KeyError: 'value' @jch

Comment: @Priyx Verify that the 'value' and 'data' columns are present in df1 and df2 before executing this code.

Comment: @Priyx I included the full solution that works for me in my answer.

Comment: @Priyx Also note that this code only works if both 'value' and 'data' are columns.  If 'value is instead an index then this code will fail with a KeyError: 'value'

Comment: Actually value and data are index, I have also given them as an example @jch